# Facebook like count discrepancy for community pages between frontend and graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Being logged and unlogged to facebook, when I'm in the facebook UI and visit this URL: https://www.facebook.com/pages/The-Matrix-Revolutions/103732522998325

I can see: " 233,368 people like this topic "

But when i browse with the facebook graph API (with and without access token) it's not the same number of likes:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=103732522998325%3Ffields%3Dlikes
{
  "likes": 179758, 
  "id": "103732522998325"
}

It's a huge difference.

Does anyone know how I could retrieve the frontend information with facebook API (i.e. 233,368 people like this topic) ?